# Sum and finding the largest number in pandas using pivot tables

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot-table

I got a project and want to know from more experienced users about the best way to reach the goal. Please, help a newbie)

What is needed:

- Find the total value of the column “Metric Ton”
- Find the total value for each class in column “Class” (like: “HRW” – number, “HRS” – number, and etc.)
- Find the total value for each destination in column “Destination” (like: “Canada” - number, “China” – number, etc.)

What I’m doing:

1. Creating the dataFrame from bigger csv and filtering needed columns, so my frame looks like this:

   ```
   inspections = pd.read_csv("CY2020.csv", usecols = ["Thursday", "Grade", "Class", "Grain", "Destination", "Metric Ton" ], parse_dates = ["Thursday"])

   wheat = inspections["Grain"].str.contains("WHEAT")

   current_week = inspections["Thursday"] == "2020-07-16"

   weekly = inspections[wheat & current_week]

   weekly.head(10)
   ```

   [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqbti.png)
2. Creating  pivot table and finding out the total value of column “Metric Ton”:

   ```
   piv = weekly.pivot_table(values = "Metric Ton", index = ["Destination"], columns = "Class", aggfunc = "sum", fill_value = 0)
   piv.sum().sum()
   ```

   [pivot_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqbti.png)
3. Finding out total values for each class and sorting them:

   ```
   piv.sum().sort_values(ascending = False)
   ```
4. Finding out total values for each destination and sorting them:

   ```
   piv.sum(1).sort_values(ascending = False)
   ```

So, my questions:

1. Is there a way to make it all quicker with less of code?
2. How can I create column “Total”, which will contain the sum of values of each row?
3. How can I create the row with “Total” in the bottom, which will contain the sum of values of each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to set up the grain-processing pipeline.  First, create a function with the download and calculation logic.

```
def process_grain(data_file, current_week, grain):
    
    fields = ["Thursday", "Grade", "Class", "Grain", "Destination", "Metric Ton" ]
    results = dict()
    
    with open(data_file, 'rt') as handle:
        table = (pd.read_csv(handle, 
                             usecols = fields,
                             parse_dates = ["Thursday"])
                 .query('Thursday == @current_week and Grain == @grain')
                 .pivot_table(values = "Metric Ton", 
                              index = "Destination",
                              columns = "Class",                              
                              aggfunc = "sum",
                              fill_value = 0,
                              margins = True,
                              margins_name = "Total"
                             )
                )
    results['by_dest_class'] = table
    results['by_dest']       = table.sum(axis=0).iloc[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)
    results['by_class']      = table.sum(axis=1).iloc[:-1].sort_values(ascending=False)
    results['metric_ton']    = table.at['Total', 'Total']
    
    return results
```

Second, set up the arguments and call the function.  The function returns a data frame (the pivot table); two series (sub-totals by class and by destination), and a scalar (total metric tons for the week).

```
data_file = 'CY2020.csv'
current_week = '2020-07-16'
grain = 'WHEAT'

results = process_grain(data_file, current_week, grain)
```

Finally, we can iterate over the results dictionary, to see key names and value data types:

```
for k, v in results.items():
    print('{:16s} {}'.format(k, type(v)))

by_dest_class    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
by_dest          <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
by_class         <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
metric_ton       <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You’ve cut the code like more than by a half and it’s really easy to read and understand, what is going on there. I’ve tried to do it this way, but created a function only for the output and it looks like s##t)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment and for the link to the original data.  Please can you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margins` and `margins_name` in the pivot_table() command, to obtain totals for the rows and columns.  The revised function call would be:

```
weekly.pivot_table(values = "Metric Ton", 
                   index = "Destination",
                   columns = "Class",
                   aggfunc = "sum",
                   fill_value = 0,
                   margins = True,
                   margins_name = "Total"
                   
)
```

Can you post a few rows of the csv file?  It might be possible to slightly streamline the steps from read_csv() to pivot_table().

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Margin parameters are super awesome and didn’t know about them. As for initial csv file, I can show a few rows, but it’s too large and really messy. It has like 100+ columns most of which are useless, at least in this example. What if I provide a link to the sheet? The name would be “Export Grain Inspection 2020”.


https://fgisonline.ams.usda.gov/ExportGrainReport/default.aspx/